# Is there log which record the operation of files in linux

Tags: linux, logging

Is there log which record the operation of files in linux. Just like, if some users rename or delete or add some files, can root user see the records of the operations. Do these logs exists in linux. 
Thx

Answer (score 2):

Not by default. The kernel has an [audit framework](http://doc.opensuse.org/products/draft/SLES/SLES-security_sd_draft/cha.audit.comp.html) for this, but it must be manually enabled.

Answer (score 0):

If you're root, you can find them in the users' `.bash_history` files (assuming they're using Bash as the shell; other shells keep their histories elsewhere).

Answer (score 0):

`.bash_history` file in home folder of each user contains only commands that were entered by this user in console (end executed as well, that wend wrong does not get in that file), it is not about file operations. Also, the same information you could get by `history` command.

I think it is impossible to get exactly the history of file operations, but what you can achieve is to get all file operations for each command that you want - use `strace` for it. Like `strace -e trace=open groupadd blabla`.